Access DB - After Insert
Greeting all,
I am attempting to setup a trigger to run when I insert a record into Table A (Agents) that will create the supporting record in Table B (AgentInfo). I think I have a good idea on how to get the record inserted, but I have ran into an issue. Table A has their employees name listed at Lastname, Firstname and Table B is Firstname Lastname.
I already have a module in the DB that will create the record for me BUT I have to remember to run it every time I add a new employee. It looks something like this:
Sub addAgentInfo()
    Dim mydb As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset, rs2 As DAO.Recordset
    Set mydb = CurrentDb
    Set rs = mydb.OpenRecordset("Select * from Agents where isnull(status) = true")
    Do While rs.EOF = False
        Set rs2 = mydb.OpenRecordset("select * from agentinfo where Agent_Access_ID = " & rs!Agent_Access_ID)
        If rs2.EOF Then
            rs2.AddNew
            rs2!Agent_Access_ID = rs!Agent_Access_ID
            rs2!FirstLast = Split(rs!Agent_Name, ", ")(1) & " " & Split(rs!Agent_Name, ", ")(0)
            rs2!pattern = "5x8"
            rs2!lunchduration = 30
            rs2!starttime = "8:00 AM"
            rs2!endtime = "4:30 PM"
            rs2!scheduleinfo = ""
            rs2!istempshift = False
            rs2!notes = ""
            rs2!loa = False
            rs2!fmla = False
            rs2!PendingLOA = False
            rs2!PendingFMLA = False
            rs2!LOAFMLAStartDate = Null
            rs2!LOAFMLAEndDate = Null
            rs2.Update
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End Sub

Is there a way to do the Split() function in the "Create Record" action in the After Insert trigger OR just run the function I already have made?

You can use Data Macro. By the way, how do you guarantee that names are always in two parts and not more?

Hopefully, you are using a form for data entry and not directly with table. Can use form events. Or bind form to table and don't use code to enter data.

we are unfortunately editing the table directly. this was created by a dev 5 years ago and we have to keep everything as it due to legacy applications that use it

Legacy applications do what - pull data from tables? What has that got to do with how you get data into tables?

I ended up doing this in the After Insert:

